# Intercept EmberJs Routing events

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Where can I intercept routing events from the EmberJs router?

When the browser hits a subroute like

```
https://server/posts/5/comments
```

I want to intercept the events and actions and inject custom or trigger custom logic instead of redering stuff to an outlet...

Is there a hook?

EDIT:@sabithpocker ist right maybe I should give more detail about what I am trying to do...
Actually I want to have a list of posts (resource posts) so far so good.

Now I want to show a comments view inline of a certain post with a link-to helper. So if someone clicks on posts/5/comments I want to highjack routing and send a message to show the dialog on the posts with the id 5 (inline).

Comment: try async routing using promises and `beforeModel` hook in router. Still not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: if you need to generically hook to all route changes, look at Ember.Router's didTransition hook

Comment: @sabithpocker I edited the question to provide more content

Comment: @MeoriOransky I'll give it a try .. I think I would need something global like you mentioned